# Morse code help

Tags: morse-code

http://vocaroo.com/i/s0fsMOJ82A7k

Trying to decipher this morse code if someone can help me. It's 14 characters long and the first lot is Illuminatih I think.

Comment: It just repeats ILLUMINATI6543.

Answer (score 4):

Well, a good starting way to solve this issue is to look up programs that do CW decoding and try out one of them. I'll give an example for decoding in [FL-DIGI](https://sourceforge.net/projects/fldigi/?source=directory).

So first, you need to enable an audio source that will allow you to record what your loudspeakers are playing. In Windows, for example, this is called Stereo Mix.

Next step is to get the FL-DIGI software. Start it up and it will ask you to configure it at first. You can skip the wizard, since you won't be controlling a radio with it.

Next, in the Op Mode menu select CW. You'll see two red bars appear in the waterfall display. After that go to configure menu and click on sound card. There, under capture, select Stereo Mix.

Now you can play your audio. The next step requires a bit of experience, since you'll need to identify the Morse code in the waterfall.

Here's a picture of how it all looks like:
[image: Morse code decoding]

So click on the Morse code in the waterfall and the two red bars will center on it. Now, use the two arrows next to the number 18 on my picture, to adjust the distance between the bars, so that the bars are as wide as the signal is. This is to ensure proper timing. Otherwise, spaces between words and numbers can be incorrectly decoded. If you aren't getting any decoding, take a look at the squelch setting on the right side. You need to adjust the slider so that the green bar is above the slider when you have code coming in, but below when you don't. This is to ensure that the program isn't trying to decode background noise.

Hopefully, if it all went fine, you'll have a good decode. If it didn't mess around with the decode speed until it comes out fine.

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Illuminati5643
Repeated in a loop

The above answer with the digits as 6543 is wrong.

And it is easy to copy it by ear

Comment: Welcome to ham.SE!  We recommend that all new users take [the tour](http://www.ham.stackexchange.com/tour), and also read [this helpful advice](http://ham.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I agree with John, it says ILLUMINATI5643 in a loop.